# Learning Assistance with Elasticsearch Querying

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm really new to Elasticsearch (specifically using 5.4.0) querying, and I'm trying to learn by doing some examples. I thought I had a simple example, but I'm stumped.

I have a time based index of airplane departure events (departures-Y-M-D) and a time based index of airplane arrival events (arrivals-Y-M-D). The departure documents have the `flight number`, `timestamp` the departure occurred, the airport the airplane departed from (`origin`), and the planned `destination` airport.

```
{
  "flight" : "DAL123",
  "timestamp" : 1497390313000,
  "origin" : "KATL",
  "destination" : "KMSP"
}
```

The arrival documents are basically the same structure with slightly different meanings. They have the `flight number`, `timestamp` the arrival occurred, the airport the airplane originally departed from (`origin`), and the airport the flight actually landed in (`destination`).

```
{
  "flight" : "DAL123",
  "timestamp" : 1497390313000,
  "origin" : "KATL",
  "destination" : "KMSP"
}
```

I'm trying to come up with a query that will give me the top 20 busiest airports based on the total number of departures and arrivals each airport has had over the past 30 days. For each airport returned, I want the number of departures that occurred in the 30 day span, the number of arrivals that occurred in the 30 day span, the sum of these two numbers, and the average daily number of departure/arrival events (sum / 30 days).

If I were to write some sort of pseudo-sql (because I feel its probably a bit more clear as to what I am asking), it would be something like this:

```
select
  departures.origin as airport
  count(departures.*) as departures
  count(arrivals.*) as arrivals
  (count(departures.*) + count(arrivals.*)) as total
  (total / 30) as average
from departures
join arrivals
  on departures.origin = arrivals.destination
where timestamp <= midnight_of_today
  and timestamp >= midnight_of_today - 30 days
group by airport
order by count descending
limit 20;
```

I've been focusing a lot of my time looking at aggregations but there is so much capability with ES that I'm concerned on I'm focusing in the wrong area.

Any help is appreciated. Even if it is just pointing me to examples or documentation that will help.